# Swift - Check if end of String is a symbol

Tags: string, swift

Is there any way to tell Swift to check if a string ends with a symbol.

for example how can I write the code below in swift?

```
var string = "myString*"

if string ends with "*" {
    .... do something 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` has a method `hasSuffix()`

```
var string = "myString*"

if string.hasSuffix("*") {
    .... do something 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `hasSuffix` function.

```
let string = "Hello world!"

if string.hasSuffix("!") {
    // do something
}
```